# Data Validation Macro, custom specified range

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I am writing a code in excel (VBA) that involves creating a Data Validation list from a range of cells in the same sheet. However this range changes by size and by content.

Part of the code I am using pertained to data validation is found herein:

```
 With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=RangeData
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Where RangeData is the variable range that I defined earlier.

The first issue I have is with the RangeData, I am getting an error. I would like to know if there is an alternate way to specify the range. Please keep in mind that the range is frequently changing.

Second, I would like the macro to launch whenever I insert a new row in the table. I can't seem to work out how to do it.

Your responses are highly appreciated and thanks in advance for you time!

Comment: Post the code that **Dim**s *RangeData* and establishes its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the sheet tab and select view code, you can either type the code into the Worksheet_Change event or just copy and paste it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
    Rng.Name = "RangeData"

    With Range("C1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="=RangeData"
    End With

End Sub
```

Not knowing what is the selected cells, I used range("C1") for your data validation.

[image: enter code]

[image: data val]